# ubuntu: questions about security

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security

I am using multi-core server equipped with Ubuntu 20.04 OSX. I have some questions about security and the overall access to the machine.

1. Assuming that I am only one Administrator on the workstation, would it be possible for someone to access to my files located anywhere (including desktop folder)?
2. How could I improve overall security ?

Comment: 1. Yes if you give someone your credentials to log in. Yes if you enable sharing and someone else can reach your machine across the network. Yes if someone can physically extract the storage device from your machine. Are those likely? You don't give us your starting position. 2. "Improve" is a relative term. You would need to explain where you're starting from, and what you want to achieve

Comment: What is "OSX" in "Ubuntu 20.04 OSX"? Also what type of security are you concerned about? Physical access? Who is "someone"? A user on the system, or your neighbour?

Comment: well basically if I an only one admin on the machine, could someone access to my filles located e.g. on the desktop and manipulante with them ??  The machine physically accesible for everyone who may come to the office :-)

Comment: If a attacker has physical access and enough time, even a password won't help you. He will just boot from a USB-stick and all files will be both readable and writable for him. To prevent this a encrypted filesystem will help. (e.g. LUKS)

Comment: If you allow physical access and you are in a hostile environment, then you are not the only administrator on the system.

Comment: Right thank you! What could be a better way to securise something located e.g. on the desctop ? ;-)

Answer (score -5):

Depends on version of build of Ubuntu. For example, in ubuntu 20.04.1 it is possible delete files, while in ubuntu 20.04.4 for this routine need admin privilegues. If it possible, in your system giw rights ONLY for admin for write and execute, all other have to permitted only to read. I don`t know, maybe several programmes would break.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).